# What would cause the existence of a /sdcard/logfile.log?

Tags: sd-card, logging

Since quite some time I've been getting a file `/sdcard/logfile.log` which gets really big quickly, last time I checked it was about 2MB. That file seems a general system log since I remember seeing references to several applications. How can I find out what is causing this?

Comment: Have you tried opening up the log file to see what is in it? Log files usually contain tasks performed by an app, with that you can pinpoint the app. Why don't you paste the log file here?

Comment: I'd recommend against pasting the whole log here, rather use a pasting service like [pastebin.com](http://www.pastebin.com) or paste only relevant parts of the log.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that On{X} was causing this. No logfile is created anymore in SD card since the application has been uninstalled.